# Web api getbyid with regular expression aspi.net web api 2

Tags: c#, regex, webapi

i want to use regular expression to search id in web api and the code is connected to sql server database. i want to add regular expression to my code, is that possible?

My Code:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Getbyid(int id)
    {
        List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "Select UserID, Name, Mobile, Access, Date From tblTest";
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            draft.Add(new TestClass()
                {
                    UserId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr.GetValue(0)),
                    Name = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                    Mobile = sdr.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                    Access = Convert.ToInt32(sdr.GetValue(3)),
                    Date = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr.GetValue(4))
                });
        }
        return Ok(draft);
    }

where can i add regular expression in my code to use the web link search the result what i want in the expectation result?
```

Comment: In your sample, the condition is pretty simple; it's only a `StartsWith`. For this kind of queries, you would not need a regular expression (which might also be an attack vector, see Regular Expression Injection). In an optimal solution, you'd include the condition in the query so that the DB can do the filtering and does not return unnecessary data.

Comment: I have lots of different types of id to search in database, not only find for one record, what i want is make the id can search for different condition, like AB can find ABC0001 or BAD can find BAD001

Comment: Can "BC" find "BCD001" and "ABC001" or only "BCD001"?

Comment: just correct it, sorry

Comment: Which fields do you want to filter? `Name`? `UserId` is an integer in your sample, so it can't contain data like "ABC001".

Comment: UserId is the Field that Use String in my sample

Comment: You can use LIKE operator in SQL query to search for a text anywhere in the column.  `"Select UserID, Name, Mobile, Access, Date From tblTest where UserId LIKE '%" + id + "%'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample, I assume that you only want to implement a starts-with-filter for `UserId`. In this case, you do not need to use regular expressions. These have their downsides (security considerations, complexity, varying support by DBMS) so the following approach performs the search with a simple starts-with-query that is run on the DB server:

```
[HttpGet()]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string search)
{
    List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn))
    {
      // The query uses a parameterized condition that checks 
      // whether the search term occurs at position 1 in the UserId
      string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Access, Date " + 
        "FROM tblTest " + 
        "WHERE CHARINDEX(@search, UserId) = 1";
      sqlconn.Open();
      SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
      // The following command adds the parameter with its value
      sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);
      using (SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
          draft.Add(new TestClass()
          {
            UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
            Name = sdr.GetString(1),
            Mobile = sdr.GetString(2),
            Access = sdr.GetInt32(3),
            Date = sdr.GetDateTime(4)
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return Ok(draft);
}
```

You can call this method like this (put in your controller names etc):

```
/controller?search=AB
```

Above code is a sample, adjust it to your needs and situation.

---

If some of the columns are null, you need to check them before reading the value. The following sample assumes that `Mobile` can be null:

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
  var mobile = sdr.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : sdr.GetString(2);
  draft.Add(new TestClass()
  {
    UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
    Name = sdr.GetString(1),
    Mobile = mobile,
    Access = sdr.GetInt32(3),
    Date = sdr.GetDateTime(4)
  });
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246976/discussion-between-markus-and-cloudy).